# python understanding how the print hexstring works

Tags: python

```
>>> s1='\x0195.0\x000.1C\x00.00.\x0005'
>>> print(s1)
95.00.1C.00.05
>>> s2='\x0095.0\x000.1C\x00.00.\x0005'
>>> s1==s2
False
>>> print(s2)
95.00.1C.00.05
>>> ','.join(set([s1, s2]))
'\x0095.0\x000.1C\x00.00.\x0005,\x0195.0\x000.1C\x00.00.\x0005'
```

How can i convert `s` to a string the way print does it for comparison ?

To give you an idea, Im trying to get a unique list values

```
>>> [x1,x2] = ["95.00.1C.00.05", "95.00.1C.00.05"]
>>> ','.join(set([x1, x2]))
'95.00.1C.00.05'
```

so im looking for how to convert s1 -> x1 and s2 -> x2, in python2

Comment: `print` always returns `None`. That is why the last condition is true. Your strings are different, and even their visual representations could be different. They look the same because `'\x00'` happens to be invisible on your terminal. What _exactly_ do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Your code is based on wrong assumptions, namely that ``print`` would perform any conversion. Please clearly define what you actually want to achieve – in specific, please define ``s`` and the general shape of ``s1`` (does it have only null-bytes added? does it have junk only added before numbers, or between digits as well?). It might also help to know why you are in this situation in the first place, i.e. what is your use-case.

Comment: Your example works with *any* string: `print('foo') == print('bar')` is `True`. That's because you're comparing the return value of `print`, which is `None`.

Comment: that was silly of me to compare prints, sorry about that, Ive made changes to the details to provide more info on what im trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to your question that comes to my mind is the elimination of non-printable (or, rather, "oddly-printable") characters:

```
"".join([char for char in s1 if char.isprintable()])
#'95.00.1C.00.05'
```